# Making Application Context Globally Available - Good/Bad Idea?

Tags: java, android, android-context

I find throughout my code I often require access to the Application Context.

Instead of passing Context around everywhere, I have it globally available via the following Application Class Extension:

```
public class App extends Application {
    static private Context _appContext;
    static public Context getContext(){ return _appContext;}

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        _appContext=this;
}
```

and just access it via:
`App.getContext();`

Question: is this a good or bad design idea?  And why?  Is there a recommended practice?

Comment: If your "global" context handle a small amount of views and variables, you can do... but not a best practice. If the "global context" has much variables, views to store in RAM, this is a bad idea.

Comment: "Context depend on where it come from oringinary": https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/

Comment: I thin refactoring the code so it is **not** tightly coupled with *context* is a better way to go.

Comment: @Paulo I think that only applies to an Activity Context - because you would cause a memory leak by maintaining a reference to those View's etc after the Activity has been destroyed.  This does not apply to an Application Context, which exists for the life of the Application.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `getApplicationContext()`or`(App)getApplication()` everywhere ,why you do this?

Comment: Good question. Because you can't actually use getApplicationContext everywhere, e.g in custom classes.  You can only use it in classes that derive from Context, such as Activity and Application.